# How do you find the shortest path quickly in a breadth first search?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I'm using breadth first search to find a location in a graph, and I'm pretty sure my algorithm works correctly, but I'm having troubling finding the shortest path to the result when I'm done.  Essentially, I can get from my start location to my end location using BFS, but I don't know how to construct the shortest path from the end to the beginning.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Finding the shortest path between two points actually includes the problem of finding those points, so the fact that you already have a working BFS brings you no closer to the shortest path problem.

You have many options for a shortest path algorithm - A*, Dijkstra, Bellman-Ford just to name a few - so please check them out.

Comment: I think the OP is assuming that the graph is unweighted.

Comment: @Bob John, You need to specify if the graph is weighted and/or directed. If it is neither, then backtracking the BFS will give you a solution. Note that there may be multiple shortest paths (of equal length).

Answer (score 5):

One option would be the following.  Create some sort of way of associating each node with a "parent" node (perhaps a hash table, or perhaps by adding a "parent" field to whatever type represents a node).  Then, whenever you dequeue a node u from the queue and are about to add a node v into the queue, set v's parent pointer to be the node u.  This marks that the way you got to node v was by following the path to u, then extending the path by one edge to get to v.

Once you've done this and finished your BFS, you can read off the reverse of the shortest path by starting with the destination node, then repeatedly following the parent pointer until you arrive back at the start node.  Once you have this, you can just reverse this path to get back the actual shortest path.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This assumes that the shortest path is by tracing backwards from the intial BFS, which is definitely not true in general.

Comment: @CongXu- Definitely.  I assumed that since the OP was using a BFS in the first place that the graph was unweighted, in which case BFS does find the shortest path from the source node to each destination node.  In a weighted graph, you would definitely use another algorithm (Dijkstra, Bellman-Ford, etc.)

Comment: +1 excellent answer. Would it be possible to mark unvisited nodes with `null`, and visited nodes with a pointer to the parent (you do have to mark nodes in BFS, right? Man, I'm rusty).

Comment: @Patrick87- Yep, that definitely works.  In fact, that's probably the easiest way to implement BFS.